# Edit and crop uploaded image

Tags: php, image, resize, crop, uploader

Can you help me to edit this code?

```
function insert_lenses(){
    // to get userid
  $reg=$_SESSION['myusername'];
  $result_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$reg'");

  while($row_users = mysql_fetch_array($result_users))
    {
    $uid=$row_users[id];
    }

  $uploader = $_POST['uploader'];
  $path = 'photos/';
  $image=$_FILES['img_name'];
  $img_title=$_POST['title'];
  $img_tag=$_POST['tags'];
  $img_desc=$_POST['description'];
  $img_status=$_POST['status'];
  $lenses_id=$_POST['lenses'];
  $cam_id=$_POST['cams'];
  $date = date("d.m.Y");
  //------------------------------------------
  $image_size=$_FILES['img_name']['size'];
  $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['img_name']['name']);
  $extension = getExtension($filename);
  $extension = strtolower($extension);

  $image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
  $newname=$path.$image_name;
  $copied = copy($_FILES['img_name']['tmp_name'], $newname);


  if ($copied) {
    $sql=mysql_query("insert into images (uid, lid, imageurl, img_date, imagesize, imagedesc, imagetitle, imagetag, status,cam,lens,user_name,img_w,img_h)
VALUES('$uid','$lenses_id','$newname','$date','$image_size','$img_desc','$img_title','$img_tag','$$img_status','$cam_id','$lenses_id','$uploader','$w','$h')");



    return true;
  }else{
    echo "<center><h3>There are An Errors In Uploading!</h3></center>";
    return false;
  }
}


function getExtension($str) {
  $i = strrpos($str,".");
  if (!$i) { return ""; }
  $l = strlen($str) - $i;
  $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
  return $ext;
}

$reg=$_SESSION['myusername'];
$result_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$reg'");

while($row_users = mysql_fetch_array($result_users))
  {
  $getid=$row_users[id];
  }
```

I need to add in this function RESIZE AND CROP IMAGE Like flickr and facebook img, I made a new folder: /img_croped

I want to insert the new image in this folder with ( resize and crop 58*58px )

and :

```
 mysql_query("insert into images (small_img) VALUES('$croped')"); // URL VALUE
```

Comment: What are the possible image types?

Comment: Beyond the obvious SQL injection vulnerabilities, don't use the `size`, `name`, and `type` values from the $_FILES array - they're user-provided and can be subverted. As well, don't use `copy`. There's a `move_uploaded_file` function specifically to deal with file uploads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resize and crop image,check below code which helps to crop image:

```
<?php
   if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
      include('SimpleImage.php');
      $image = new SimpleImage();
      $image->load($_FILES['uploaded_image']['tmp_name']);
      $image->resizeToWidth(300);
      $image->resizeToHeight(200);
      $image->save('resizeImage.jpg');
      //$image->output();
   } else {
?>   <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="uploaded_image" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
   </form><?php
   }
?>
```

Check [<s>this link</s>](http://sanjeevkumarjha.com.np/how-to-resize-and-crop-image) (dead) to find class of resize image and more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try imagemagick for this:

```
exec( "convert $newname -resize 58x58^ -gravity center -extent 58x58 /img_croped/$filename");
```

This will resize shorter side to 58, then crop longer side to 58 px (cutting off edges)

Comment: thanks for reply but the code is doesn't work with my function

i did it, but the function doesn't upload to img_croped folder

Comment: @rixlinux - I'm not sure if you have your `/img_croped` in the root like you have in your question, or somewhere else... The last parameter to the command line is where this file should be saved. Change it to the folder and file name you need, and it should work. If not - post what error you're getting.