# PHP Image uploader (with resize and crop)

Tags: php, image, upload, resize, crop

I'm creating a form which should allow a user to upload a photo (along with other form elements such as text boxes) but I'm in need of a PHP script which will allow the photo to be uploaded, and if the image does not conform to specific dimensions to be resized and then cropped (from bottom center of the image).

Can you recommend any scripts available?

Answer (score 7):

A fast search gave me the following results.

If I was you I would use [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) with my own [uploading script](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

- [php- Edit upload file + Crop image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255421/php-edit-upload-file-crop-image)
- [upload and crop image before sending it to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735786/upload-and-crop-image-before-sending-it-to-the-server)
- [Image uploader + crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176317/image-uploader-crop)

Answer (score 5):

I would like to recommend this example.

http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop/

Good luck.

Prasad.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend `upload.class.php`. It is the best class for handling images.

You can find it here:
http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm